# Add arrow to the same node in latex tikz

Tags: latex, tikz

I'm trying to create the schema in tikz latex. I need to have arrows between nodes and arrows to the same node. The arrow to the same node has to be outside the node. It has to start on the top right of the box and end on the top left of the box.

How to add a bent arrow to the box as shown in the picture.
I would love to have the same arrow as shown in the screenshot.

[image: what I looking for]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1.5cm and 1cm,
ar/.style={->,>=latex},
middle_node/.style={
  draw,
  text width=1.5cm,
  minimum height=0.75cm,
  align=center
  },
end_node/.style={
  draw,
  text width=1cm,
  minimum height=0.55cm,
  align=center
  }
]

  % nodes
  \node[end_node] (start) {\textbf{start}};
  \node[middle_node,right=of start] (first_step) {a};
  \node[middle_node,right=of first_step] (second_step) {b};
  \node[middle_node,right=of second_step] (third_step) {c}; 
  \node[end_node, right=of third_step] (stop) {\textbf{stop}};

  % lines
  \draw[ar] (start) -- (first_step);
  % here i don know how to bend this arrow to the same box
  \draw[ar] (first_step.80) -- (first_step.180);
  \draw[ar] (first_step) -- (second_step);
  \draw[ar] (second_step) -- (third_step);
  \draw[ar] (third_step) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a loop like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1.5cm and 1cm,
ar/.style={->,>=latex},
middle_node/.style={
  draw,
  text width=1.5cm,
  minimum height=0.75cm,
  align=center
  },
end_node/.style={
  draw,
  text width=1cm,
  minimum height=0.55cm,
  align=center
  }
]

  % nodes
  \node[end_node] (start) {\textbf{start}};
  \node[middle_node,right=of start] (first_step) {a};
  \node[middle_node,right=of first_step] (second_step) {b};
  \node[middle_node,right=of second_step] (third_step) {c}; 
  \node[end_node, right=of third_step] (stop) {\textbf{stop}};

  % lines
  \draw[ar] (start) -- (first_step);
  % here i don know how to bend this arrow to the same box
  \draw[ar,out=120,in=60,<-] (first_step.north west) to (first_step.north east);
  \draw[ar] (first_step) -- (second_step);
  \draw[ar] (second_step) -- (third_step);
  \draw[ar] (third_step) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]